# Combined kanban and gantt chart project management tool

Tags: project-management, kanban

Current we use Trello for project management of tasks, along with Gantt charts drawn in Google Sheets. The problem is that this is all associated to a project, but our team runs up to 10 projects at a time so the Gantt charts drawn this way don't give us a global overview to try and see clashes and plan resources.

What we'd like to do is have one tool that can combine Kanban tasks and link them to Gantt chart lines. The tool should also allow us to see an overlay of all the Gantt charts so that we can have a global overview of all our projects.

So far I've been looking at the following :

- Project Place - Notes : Looks like it might do, but looking for other options also
- Zenkit - Notes: Looks like it might do, don't think Gantt charts are a live feature yet, but they are in a roadmap... Looking for other options also
- Wrike - Notes: Looks like it might do, but looking for other options also
- Elegantt (Gantt charts for Trello board. Notes : doesn't allow you to see a global overview of all projects)
- Team Gantt - Notes: Gantt charts only no direct integration with native or 3rd party Kanban boards

Comment: Would https://community.mycollab.com/ work for you? Seems OK on my side!

Answer (score 8):

You can use [OpenProject](https://www.openproject.org/) for these requirements. It is **free and open source** software. Here's how:

1. Create one root project.
2. Create a sub-project of the root project for each project in your team.
3. Use the task board feature from the "Scrum (backlogs and task board)" plugin for Kanban functionality ([instructions](https://www.openproject.org/help/agile-scrum/working-task-board/)).
4. Create a combined Gantt diagram for all projects:

   1. Set up reporting from each sub-project to the root project ([instructions](https://www.openproject.org/help/timelines/overarching-timeline-reports/)). Summary: Basically you visit "Timelines" for each sub project, click "Status reportings" there and create an entry for reporting to its parent project.
   2. Select the root project and create a timeline ("Timelines → +Timeline report"). Due to the sub-projects and status reporting settings, this timeline is a global Gantt chart for all your projects.

Comment: kanban boards are not included in the free edition

Comment: @markasoftware Not correct. According to [their pricing page](https://www.openproject.org/pricing/), only [Agile Boards](https://docs.openproject.org/user-guide/agile-boards) is a premium feature but [Scrum (backlogs and taskboard)](https://docs.openproject.org/user-guide/backlogs-scrum/taskboard) is available in the free Community Edition. To clarify, I updated the plugin name in the answer.

Comment: interesting...seems not quite as good as the real boards feature because you can't assign work packages to the boards, but have to create new descriptions. Either way, this ain't a problem for me anymore because I figured out how to enable enterprise mode by modifying the source code (https://gist.github.com/markasoftware/f5b2e55a2c2e3abb1f9eefcdf0bfff45), which is OK under the open source license.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest two options:

[Zenkit](https://www.zenkit.com/) - if you need to make your project management very user-friendly.

[Airtable](https://airtable.com/) - if you work with tons of data.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give more information on what is good about these two and how they would would work for the OP?

Comment: Airtable does not provide Gantt charts.

Comment: Zenkit lists Gantt chart as "subscribe to waitlist" indicating its not currently available == vapourware. So neither of these options actually provide a Gantt chart view.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest [Placker](https://placker.com) to get:

- Gantt chart - for visual planning across your projects
- Kanban - Single kanban and aggregated kanban boards
- Dashboards - To show metrics/reports

The nice thing about the Gantt is that you can order it in the way you want, for example by project or by member (to show the workload of the team member).

It works with Trello (real time and 2 way), there is a chrome extension on [www.ganttfortrello.com](http://ganttfortrello.com).

**Full disclosure: I created placker.**

Comment: As of 2021 September, the link to www.ganttfortrello.com no longer works.

Comment: Thanks @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket for pointing this out, this was a temporary issue and has been resolved.

Comment: You're welcome, and glad to hear it was a temporary issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you are still looking, I could also suggest [Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com/). It is an agile project management tool, so you would get a full Kanban support from predesigned task boards to WIP and reports.

Talking about Gantt chart, while it does not offer this specific feature, the Schedule feature is very similar, as it outlines all the tasks in a calendar like view according to their start and end dates. So I think it could fit your situation.

Answer (score 3):

I know it has been some time since you asked, but this may still be helpful to others looking for a similar solution.

**[Teamhood](https://teamhood.com)** is a tool that fits all of your requirements. It is a digital Kanban task board that allows to create task dependencies and visualizes them in a Gantt chart. Task dependencies are invisible in the Kanban board so that they don't distract day-to-day activities. However, the dependencies are active and won't let mark a task complete if the previous dependency is not finished.

Task dependencies are visible in the Timeline similar to a Gantt chart. Here you can easily plan with the help of dependency lines and modify anything that does not fit your plans.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest [Barvas](https://www.barvas.com), a project/task planning and management app which combines Mind Maps, Task Boards and Gantt charts all in the one tool.  It meets most of your needs but doesn't provide an overlay of all your project just yet.

With Barvas all 3 mentioned views work with the same data.  So, for example, if you add a task to your Kanban board it will automatically be available on your Gantt chart.  Same goes for the Mind Map view.

You can also apply filters to each view in case you only want certain information appearing.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Wekowork : https://www.wekowork.com. You can create a Kanban and you see all your tasks automatically in a Gantt chart.
I love it !

Answer (score 0):

[Teamgantt](http://teamgantt.com) have an integration with [Trello](http://trello.com), so that you can have gantt chart line items that reflect cards in Trello, the sync is bi directional.

For details on the integration see [HERE](https://support.teamgantt.com/article/116-trello-powerup).